# Lock C# code for different Azure webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have 2 different webjobs (one scheduled and one continuous) running in Azure. A piece of code in first webjob collides with the piece of code in second webjob (Code is not exactly same), and I want to prevent running them in parallel.

I am thinking of using a blob lease here. Alternatively, as I read [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton), Azure Webjobs SDK supports a singleton attribute. Is it possible to apply this attribute on methods in different webjobs and have a common scope (or common lock underneath).

Can you think of any alternative way ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to apply this attribute on methods in different webjobs and have a common scope (or common lock underneath).

Based on my experience, It is a good idea to use [blob lease](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-8-blob-leases/).

> Blob Leases allow you to claim ownership to a Blob. Once you have the lease you can then update the Blob or delete the Blob without worrying about another process changing it underneath you.

---

> Can you think of any alternative way ?

**ETags** are also used for optimistic concurrently control. More details we could refer to [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-6-blob-properties-metadata-etc/).

> string **ETag** (r/o) – this is an identifier for a specific version of a resource. This is used for web cache validation, and allows a client to make conditional requests. ETags are also used for optimistic concurrently control. For example, **if you were reading a blob and saved the ETag, then did some other processing and came back to upload a new version of that blob, you could read the ETag again and check it against the prior value**. If the ETag values match, then the file hasn’t changed and you can upload a new version of it. If the match fails, the storage service will return a 412 error (precondition failed).